# Pulling imagery from Sentinel2 esa:sentinel-2:l2a:v1 product in Descartes Labs

Tags: descartes-labs-platform

I am using the Descartes Labs platform. I am building a machine learning pipeline and want to run it on 10-band, 64x64, Sentinel L2A data collected over India. I used GEE Sentinel2 L2A imagery to train the model on a different platform, and am now attempting to transfer the model weights to Descartes and deploy on fresh imagery.

I wrote general helper functions that successfully search for scenes over a given DLTile and pull imagery using the `stack()` function. I am able to successfully display the pulled images for the `sentinel-2:L1C` product. However, my problem arises when I keep everything constant but change from the `sentinel-2:L1C` product to the `esa:sentinel-2:l2a:v1` product. My `scenes.search()` successfully returns a handful of scenes using `esa:sentinel-2:l2a:v1`, but then the runtime of `stack()` or `mosaic()` seems to increase by an order of magnitude, and the resulting `ndarray` object is only populated with 0 values.

I inspected the `esa:sentinel-2:l2a:v1` in the viewer and it seems to plot valid imagery. To restate the question in code, the following code works as intended and runs in less than a second, where `small_tile` is a DLTile over the Indian mainland:

```
scenes, ctx = dl.scenes.search(
    small_tile,
    cloud_fraction=0.2,
    products="sentinel-2:L1C",
    start_datetime="2020-11-01",
    end_datetime="2021-01-01",
)

x = scenes.stack(
     "red green blue", 
     ctx=small_tile, 
     resampler="med"
)  

dl.scenes.display(x[0])
```

However, switching out the `products` argument in `scenes.search()`

```
scenes, ctx = dl.scenes.search(
    small_tile,
    cloud_fraction=0.2,
    products="esa:sentinel-2:l2a:v1", # previously ""sentinel-2:L1C""
    start_datetime="2020-11-01",
    end_datetime="2021-01-01",
)
```

causes the cell to take almost a minute to run and ultimately pulls data that is populated entirely with 0s.

I ideally need to use L2A Sentinel2 data because my model is not generalizing to the LC1 Sentinel2 data.

Does anyone know what might be going on?

I have tried to adjust the start and end time of the `scenes.search()` function, have removed the `cloud_fraction` parameter, and attempted to pull imagery using both `stack()` and `mosaic()`.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the trouble with the switch from L1C to L2A! First the L2A product comes with two possible processing levels which are surface and toa (top of atmosphere) each of which have different native data types. To fix your all zeros problem, change your `scenes.stack` call to the following:

```
x = scenes.stack(
     "red green blue", 
     ctx=small_tile, 
     resampler="med",
     data_type="Float64"
)
```

The extra runtime comes from a quirk with where the L2A data is stored. The L1C product was managed by DL in-house whereas the L2A data is hosted in a public AWS bucket managed by the scientific community. For this reason, data access from L2A will be slightly longer than before.

Hope this helps!